# Spring webmvc interceptor to rewrite request and response

Tags: java, spring

I am looking for a way to intercept in spring webmvc an incoming http request and response. I need to rewrite the entire request and response.

In concrete, I need to receive a request, extract the request body and process the request body as if it were a brand new request (thus rewriting the entire request before it gets handled further). Thereafter, I need to rewrite the response that is generated and wrap it somehow.

Can anyone help and provide some pointers?

Thanks

Comment: can you use a filter?

Comment: you can use spring interceptors

Answer (score 4):

You can write interceptors in Spring MVC by implementing `HandlerInterceptor` interface. There are three methods that need to be implemented.

`preHandle(..)` is called before the actual handler is executed;

`postHandle(..)` is called after the handler is executed;

`afterCompletion(..)` is called after the complete request has finished.

These three methods should provide enough flexibility to do all kinds of preprocessing and postprocessing.

Learn more about how to place a filter in SpringMVC: http://viralpatel.net/blogs/spring-mvc-interceptor-example/

Comment: I am sorry, that's not the right way to rewrite the request. The right way is to not use SpringWebMVC, but to rely on the plain servlet api. After days, I found the right answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1046721/accessing-the-raw-body-of-a-put-or-post-request/1048123#1048123